# Copy all materials from one object to another and have the materials assign to the correct faces automatically

Tags: materials

I had to undo all of my materials and am now redoing them.

Some Objects have multiple materials on different faces.

I know how to copy materials from one object to another, but how do I make it so that it assigns the materials to the correct faces?

Example in picture.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:** Actually I Just Figured this out, on accident.

Select every blank object by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd>, then lastly, select the object with the materials correctly assigned (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd>).

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and choose *Link Object Data*.

Comment: Please don't answer within the question. Write a proper answer in the answer section so that others which might have the same problem can immediately see in the overview that this has been answered. You can even accept your own answer after a grace period and gain reputation points by doing so.

Comment: By the way, maybe you should mention that you do not have the default mouse button selection enabled, because if so `Shift`+`RMB` would place the 3D cursor in the viewport and not select multiple objects which could confuse people. The other thing is, in your screenshot it looks as if one object is going straight up while the others are slanted. If this is not done by a modifier but in the mesh itself, _Link Object Data_ would make them all straight or slanted (depending on which object you link the data to).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, rephrasing the problem to read like an actual question or expose a problem, while the solution is written as separate answer in the proper section below? Maybe add a short description of the steps accompanied by a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)